# Cases environment with SIAM document class

Tags: cases

It seems as though the SIAM class does not play nice with the cases environment. For example

```
$$
\begin{cases}
x & y
\end{cases}
$$
```

will produce the error

```
misplaced alignment tab character
```

Oddly enough,

```
$$
\begin{cases}
x \\ y
\end{cases}
$$
```

compiles, but puts x and y on the same line.

Comment: `cases` environment is defined in `amsmath` so you presumably want `\usepackage{amsmath}`  otherwise you get the original (more or less undocumented) `\cases` command that is defined in latex but really comes from plain tex and should not be used

Comment: Thanks. If you put your answer here I can accept it thereby closing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cases` *environment* is defined in `amsmath` so you presumably want

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

otherwise you get the original (more or less undocumented) `\cases` *command* that is defined in latex but really comes from plain tex and should not be used.

Comment: you might also have suggested using `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I thought about it, but one thing at a time:-)